# Wait for process in container to be up before signalling to dependent containers they can start

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a GraphQL container, hitting an Elasticsearch container. Now, in the compose file I have:

```
depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
```

but the thing is, the elasticsearch server (being a JVM process) takes time to come up. However, as far as docker is concerned it appears that this makes no difference, so compose then moves on the the GraphQL container...even though the ES is not ready. So, if a user hits the site before the ES is ready the graphql bugs out and crashes..

So, is there a way to signal to dependent containers to check a process is up, maybe first? Or must this be done in the GraphQL code...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker Compose wait for container X before starting Y](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746182/docker-compose-wait-for-container-x-before-starting-y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this via a `bash script`, and 2 compose files.

You can use `curl` against `elasticsearch` to determine its up.
Then use second compose file to bring up the second container(s).